# On button click display list items, dropdown list should not hide until button is clicked again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have looked everywhere possible as I am trying to develop a drop down button, but instead of options then the buttons display unordered list items, but when a user click off the button the the button does not close, but in order to close the button, then the button needs to be click again.

Down below you will find the way the button is when not clicked and the way the button appears when it has been clicked.

[image: The way the button appears when it has not been clicked]

[image: The way the button appears that has not been clicked]

If you also go to the following website you will see an example of the button in action by click "See our list of websites"

[Button on a website for example](https://www.rockstargames.com/cookies)

Any help would be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Share your code, it will be really more simple to help you.

Comment: "instead of options then the buttons display unordered list items"...what do you mean? What's the difference between "options" and "list items"? Who is putting them into an order? What order is that? And ok, this is a list of requirements, but what actual problems are you facing? What have you tried? What isn't working? There's nothing for us to answer here. You haven't asked us a question.

Comment: I don't have the code, because I don't know where to start with something like this, but I can send a picture of what i am talking about

Comment: Let's see the picture then.

Comment: I have updated the above with the examples

Comment: Hi @Kyle, be sure to `accept an answer` so that it would help somebody else. I noticed that most of your questions don't have accepted answers. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, key functions I used;

**.click()** for the a tag or the link, the function inside the .click() will be called.

**.slideToggle()** the ul after the click, this would hide or show the target element depending on its state.

Then add **positon:absolute** to the ul so that it wouldn't affect inline elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".toggle-button").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find("ul").slideToggle(function() {
      // Animation complete.
    });
  });
})
```

```css
.links-unordered {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.links-unordered {
  margin-top: 20px;
  min-height: 30px;
}

.links-unordered .toggle-button {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.links-unordered .toggle-button:hover,
.links-unordered .toggle-button:active,
.links-unordered .toggle-button:focus,
.links-unordered .toggle-button:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.links-unordered .toggle-button:hover {
  border-width: 2px;
}

.links-unordered ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  padding-inline-start: 20px;
}

.links-unordered ul li {
  line-height: 25px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.links-unordered a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="links-unordered">
  <a class="toggle-button" href="#">SEE OUR LIST OF WEBSITES</a>
  <ul style="display:none;">
    <li><a href="#">cdn.sc.rockstargames.com</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">lifeinvader.com</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">rockstargames.com</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">socialclub.rockstargames.com</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="links-unordered">
  <a class="toggle-button" href="#">SEE OUR LIST OF WEBSITES</a>
  <ul style="display:none;">
    <li><a href="#">cdn.sc.rockstargames.com</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">lifeinvader.com</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">rockstargames.com</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">socialclub.rockstargames.com</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand what you want. But here's a sample of what you asked, a button that when you click, show a list. And when you click on an item, the list goes out and you have the item. Hope this helps you. It's a simple code, but if you have questions, go ahead and ask!!

```js
function closeList(e) {
    var site = e.target.innerText;
    alert(site + ' clicked!!');
    document.querySelector('#dvSites').style.display = 'none';
}


function showList() {
    var dvSites = document.querySelector('#dvSites');
  
    if (dvSites.style.display === '')
        return; // already visible
 
    dvSites.style.display = '';
}

// Add eventListener to close the div
var lis = document.querySelector('#dvSites').querySelectorAll('li');
for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    lis[i].addEventListener('click', closeList);
}

// Add eventListener to open the div
document.querySelector('#btnShow').addEventListener('click', showList);
```

```html
<button id="btnShow">Show sites!!</button>
<div id="dvSites" style="display: none">
    <ul>
        <li>stackoverflow.com</li>
        <li>www.google.com</li>
        <li>www.sipmann.com</li> <!-- :) -->
    </ul>
</div>
```