# List not available after clicking on a button while trying to build a REST-API using Flask, Python and Postgresql

Tags: python, html, postgresql, flask

I am trying to build a web-app which extracts and inputs information about different city buildings using Python, Flask and HTML. At the moment I want to create a button which after clicking it will give me a list of all the buildings available on the database. The database is populated and stored in PostgreSQL. The problem is that the button is created and displayed but the list is not. I used [the second answer on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52845107/on-button-click-display-list-items-dropdown-list-should-not-hide-until-button-i) as a reference.
My Python code looks like as follows :

```
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return flask.render_template('interface.html')
@app.route('/GetBuildingsLists', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def GetBuildingsLists():
    print('Connecting to the PostgreSQL database...')
    db = pg.connect(
        host="****", 
        database="****", 
        user ="****",
        password="*****")
    db_cursor = db.cursor()
    print('PostgreSQL database version:')
    db_cursor.execute('SELECT version()')
    q = ("SELECT building_id FROM table1")
    db_cursor.execute(q)
    buildings = db_cursor.fetchall()
    unique_buildings = list(dict.fromkeys(buildings))
    db_cursor.close()
    #print(unique_buildings)
    return flask.render_template('interfaceLists.html', unique_buildings = unique_buildings)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

Meanwhile, on a template folder I have interfaceLists.html as below :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Results</title>
        <style>

            .links-unordered {
                  display: inline-block;
                  position: relative;
            }
    
            .links-unordered {
              margin-top: 20px;
              min-height: 30px;
            }
            
            .links-unordered .toggle-button {
              text-decoration: none;
              padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
              transition: 0.2s;
              border: 1px solid black;
            }
            
            .links-unordered .toggle-button:hover,
            .links-unordered .toggle-button:active,
            .links-unordered .toggle-button:focus,
            .links-unordered .toggle-button:visited {
              text-decoration: none;
              color: black;
            }
            
            .links-unordered .toggle-button:hover {
              border-width: 2px;
            }
            
            .links-unordered ul {
              position: absolute;
              top: 10px;
              margin-top: 25px;
              padding-inline-start: 20px;
            }
            
            .links-unordered ul li {
              line-height: 25px;
              padding-left: 15px;
            }
            
            .links-unordered a {
              text-decoration: none;
              color: black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="demo_script_src.js"></script>
    
        <div class="links-unordered">
          <a class="toggle-button" href="#">Buildings</a>
            {% for building in unique_buildings %}   
                  <ul style="display:none;">
                     <li><a href="#">building[0]</a></li> 
                  </ul>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I take the results from the PostgreSQL using a query in the python code and store them in the list called unique_buildings. I have tried to display afterwards the results as an unordered list but the list is not displayed.
The .js file mention in the HTML file performs the animation while using the button and it looks like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
              $(".toggle-button").click(function() {
                $(this).parent().find("ul").slideToggle(function() {
                  // Animation complete.
                });
              });
            })
```

Can someone please help me by telling what might be wrong with my script and why what I want is not working? Thank you!!

Comment: From the resultset you've created a dict which you turn into a list, you iterate over the list -- in the template -- and you attempt to access the `[0]th` element of each element within the list? Are you getting an error? If so, please edit the question to include the full traceback of the error.

Comment: Thank you @mechanical_meat for your answer. I iterate in that manner because the output I get from the instruction print(unique_buildings) is [('build1',)]